# Refreshing lookups in SPA with Breeze.js when value has changed

Tags: breeze

I have an application that records a transaction and the user can pick the category from a drop down.
Categories are loaded up at application startup as they are "mostly" static / rarely going to change.

So, in my datacontext.js I do the usual and prime my data;

```
var primeData = function () {
        var promise = Q.all([
            getLookups(),
            getBankAccountPartials(null, true)])
            .then(applyValidators);

        return promise.then(success);

        function success() {
            datacontext.lookups = {
                categories: getLocal('Categories', 'name', true),
                transactiontypes: getLocal('TransactionTypes', 'name', true),
                payees: getLocal('Payees', 'name', true)
            };
            log('Primed data', datacontext.lookups);
        }

        function applyValidators() {
            model.applyBankAccountValidators(manager.metadataStore);
        }

    };

function getLookups() {
            return EntityQuery.from('Lookups')
                .using(manager).execute()
                .then(processLookups)
                .fail(queryFailed);
        }
```

Now, occasionally in an Admin screen the user can edit and add a category.
In the categoryadd.js viewmodel my save code looks something like this (extract shown);

```
    save = function () {
                isSaving(true);
                datacontext.saveChanges()
                    .then(goToEditView).fin(complete);

                function goToEditView(result) {
                    router.replaceLocation('#/categorydetail/' + category().id());
                }

                function complete() {
                    isSaving(false);
                }
            },
```

How do I refresh just the Categories lookup data?  Or, am I just doing this wrong and should perhaps NOT have categories as a lookup?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok from my further investigations it seems Breeze.js is amazing and is synchronising automatically and knows to search out the Category and update it in its lookup list.

I checked this by calling datacontext.lookups from the browser console after the save had been performed and inspecting the objects it showed me the category name had been refreshed.

I am impressed.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: No kadumel I'm all good thanks.  I will mark it answered when I'm allowed to.

Comment: Cool, I would recommend either deleting the question or providing an answer (if you feel strongly that this question / answer will come up again in the near future for others sometimes it helps to avoid re-asking it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze.js synchronises automatically and knows to search out the Category and update it in its lookup list.

I checked this by calling datacontext.lookups from the browser console after the save had been performed and inspecting the objects it showed me the category name had been refreshed.